# The argument type 'Future<void> Function(TapPosition)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapPosition, LatLng)?'

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

```
FlutterMap(
            options: MapOptions(
            onTap: (p, point) async {
              GeoData location = await Geocoder2.getDataFromCoordinates(
                  latitude: p.latitude, longitude: p.longitude, googleMapApiKey: '');
              );
            print("${location.country}");
              setState((){
                point=p;
              });
            },
            center: LatLng(49.5, -0.09),
            zoom: 10.0
          ),
```

I am trying to use geocoder2 in my flutter app to work with maps. But I am facing this error. If someone could help, that'd be great.

```
  LatLng point=LatLng(49, -1);
```

This is my declaration of variables.
And now the errors are:

```
The getter 'latitude' isn't defined for the type 'TapPosition'.
```

```
The getter 'longitude' isn't defined for the type 'TapPosition'.
```

```
A value of type 'TapPosition' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'LatLng'.
```

```
                  point: point, builder: (ctx)=> Icon(
```

This is the error where I am trying to use point.

Comment: import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';

Comment: Using `latlong2`  will be handy because `FlutterMap` use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onTap` callback provide `tapPosition` and `point`.

```dart
typedef TapCallback = void Function(TapPosition tapPosition, LatLng point);
```

Include another parameters to solve this case like

```dart
 onTap: (tapPos, p) async {
```

More about [MapOptions](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_map/latest/flutter_map/MapOptions-class.html) and  [flutter_map/TapCallback](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_map/latest/flutter_map/TapCallback.html)

**Update**

Full snippet be like

```dart
  LatLng point = LatLng(49, -1);
  GeoData? location;
   ...
FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(
          onTap: (f, p) async {
            p.latitude;
            location = await Geocoder2.getDataFromCoordinates(
                latitude: p.latitude,
                longitude: p.longitude,
                googleMapApiKey: '');
            setState(() {
              point = p;
            });
          },
          zoom: 10.0,
          center: LatLng(49, -1)),
    );
```

Note thing about use of packages

> `latlong2` and `geocoder2`

Comment: How do I provide TapCallback for this, declare it separately from onTap?

Comment: nope, you just need to replace `onTap: (p) ` with `onTap: (tapPos, p) ` you just need to include another parameter on callback, it can be any ,

Comment: Even if that works, there are errors on geocoder2

Comment: The second argument provides `LatLng`,

Comment: The getter 'latitude' isn't defined for the type 'TapPosition'. This is new error then, for longitude too.

Comment: It will  be like `onTap: (tapPos, p) async {
...   p.latitude;`

Comment: test updated snippet

Comment: should I declare it as Latlng2 ?

Comment: I still get the error for getter ..latitute and longitude one. Also, how can I pass GeoData to list?

Comment: The error occurs from mismatch of latlng pck, try using [latlong2](https://pub.dev/packages/latlong2) or you can do it manually like `point = LatLng(p.latitude, p.longitude)`